# Can't find a solution for innerjoin to work with my store

Tags: mysql

What I'm trying to do is to show shoppinglista.Avdelning with name and shoppinglista.butik with name in a table together.
then sort these by name. I cant' figure out how to write the innerjoin to work.

```
CREATE TABLE shoppinglista (
  id int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  namn varchar(255),
  pris INT,
  avdelningId INT,
  butiksId INT
);

CREATE TABLE avdelning (
  id int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  namn varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE butik (
  id int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  namn varchar(255)
);


ALTER TABLE avdelning ADD FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES shoppinglista (avdelningId);
ALTER TABLE butik ADD FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES shoppinglista (butiksId);



SELECT * FROM shoppinglista;
SELECT * FROM avdelning;
SELECT * FROM butik;


INSERT INTO shoppinglista (namn, pris, avdelningId, butiksId)
VALUES ('Bakpotatis Klass 1', '9.95', 1, 1 ),
       ('Zucchini Klass 1', '9.95', 1, 1),
       ('Lättmjölk 0,5%', '10.95', 2, 1),
       ('Avokodo Klass 1', '13.95', 1, 1),
       ('Standardmjölk 3%', '15.95', 2, 1),
       ('Mellanmjölk 1.5% Ekologisk', '16.95', 2, 1),
       ('Svennes Kaviar Mildrökt', '22.95', 3, 1);

INSERT INTO avdelning (namn)
VALUES
       ('Grönsaker'),
       ('Mejeri'),
       ('Fisk & skaldjur');


INSERT INTO butik (namn)
VALUES ('Hemköp'),
       ('Knasum');

SELECT * FROM shoppinglista;
SELECT * FROM avdelning;
SELECT * FROM butik;
```

Comment: You could improve this question by adding desired outcome. Also add what you tried so we can comment on where you went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Start with this:

```
Select
      s.*
    , a.namn as Avdelningnamn
    , b.namn as buitknamn
From shoppinglista as s
Inner join avdelning as a on s.avdelningId 
= a.id
Inner join butik as b on s.butiksId = b.id
```